# Separate laminate from chipboard

Tags: wood

I am trying to separate the thin layer of laminate that is glued to the chipboard.

I have so far managed to cut the piece across the width, and after soaking it in water for several days the chipboard does come off a little if a scrape it with the teeth of a saw, but there is a high risk of damaging the laminate.

Is there a solvent that would work in this case?

This is originally an 18mm chipboard typically used in kitchen cabinet.

The piece of wood in question:
[image: chipboard with laminate]

Comment: Why ... ? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @brhans This could be a way to hide a 7cm (diameter) hole in a cabinet (that I can only access from the front). I would nail, screw, or glue it on top of the hole.

Comment: @Jelefra- to repair a hole in a cabinet cut a plug from a scrap piece than using a bit the same size as the plug cut a hole in the damaged area. The plug  can be glued into the hole.

Comment: Are you aware you can buy thin sheets of wood veneer?

Comment: @ojait Good point, thank you. That would solve the problem. The only downside in my case is that it requires me to buy something that I may not use in the future. I'd like to rule out any other free option first.

Comment: @TedMittelstaedt I hadn't considered that option, thank you. I'm not sure how I could find a matching piece though. I happen to have leftover pieces that match so I was trying to use that.

Comment: The glue used is usually contact cement. It can usually be softened by solvent but getting to the glue will be tough. Hot water will cause the particle board to swell and fall apart faster than just cold water once mst of the wood fiber is removed then a solvent like acetone or MEK may work but be careful some really good solvents can damage the laminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a hot glue used, try a wet / damp towel and a hot iron to loosen it, but you will need to do so while it is extremely hot. Be careful. A broad putty knife may be handy for this.
[image]

Picture courtesy Lowes

This may not be an easy solution, while hot the laminate will be very weak and flimsy, let alone the hot glue may want to bond the laminate to the knife as you are going, if it does anything at all. Get it too hot, it will damage the laminate too.

If you really feel you need to cover the hole, recut the hole to a square opening, then cut the filler piece to match the size of the hole. Another tip would be to taper the sides of the new cut and the filler so it will stop at a given place.

Answer (score 1):

After soaking the piece the wood fibers of the under the plastic will soften and become pliable. Rather than risking a wayward cut with a saw blade try removing the wood chips with a floor scraper or a paint scraper with a knob over the blade. lay the piece on a flat smooth surface while working.

Hopefully most of the wood fibers will be scraped off, but most likely some residual wood and glue will remain on the plastic. This can further be removed with an orbital sander (or any hand sander) with a 60-80 grit disk/sheet. Again you want to keep the plastic veneer on a flat surface to avoid splitting it.